# XSL test for text present in node when another one is in the way

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML is it possible to test to see if there is any text present after the list but still within the quote-para node. This is probably really basic but I can't get my head around where to start with this one:

```
<quote-block open="&quot;" close="&quot;">
<quote-para>In the result I would restate the <emphasis strength="normal">Windsurfing</emphasis>
    questions thus: <list prefix-rules="specified">
        <item prefix="(1)">
            <list prefix-rules="specified">
                <item prefix="(a)">
                    <para>Identify the notional <quote open="&quot;" close="&quot;"
                            >person skilled in the art</quote></para>
                </item>
                <item prefix="(b)">
                    <para>Identify the relevant common general knowledge of that person;</para>
                </item>
            </list>
        </item>
        <item prefix="(2)">
            <para>Identify the inventive concept of the claim in question or if that cannot
                readily be done, construe it;</para>
        </item>
        <item prefix="(3)">
            <para>Identify what, if any, differences exist between the matter cited as forming
                part of the <quote open="&quot;" close="&quot;">state of the art</quote>
                and the inventive concept of the claim or the claim as construed;</para>
        </item>
        <item prefix="(4)">
            <para>Viewed without any knowledge of the alleged invention as claimed, do those
                differences constitute steps which would have been obvious to the person skilled
                in the art or do they require any degree of invention?</para>
        </item>
    </list>
</quote-para>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean text not wrapped in another element?  Try this XPath:

```
//quote-para/list/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I meant, seems so obvious now. Cheers